# Any way to use lists of different type in one v-for loop without failing type checks?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've written a component that is used to render two datasets. The nature of the data is different in both data sets:

```
state.articleTypeList: string[]
state.renderPriceClassNameList: {[key: string]: string[]}
```

I am rendering both data sets in one v-for component with the help of `ternary operators`:

```
<div
  v-for="(rootItem, key) in openTab === 1
    ? state.articleTypeList
    : state.renderPriceClassNameList"
  :key="key">
  <div
    @click="
      openTab === 1 ? getArticleList(rootItem) : getPriceClass(rootItem)
    "
    ...
```

typescript shows for `rootItem` that: `Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` but this type check should never occur because type `string | string[]` should only be used when `openTab !== 1`.

I've searched the web on how to solve this error but only landed in this [git issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863) which provides no solution. My best bet is to render each dataset in its own v-for loop instead of using `ternary operators` but this would require reworking the whole component.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not know that the value of `rootItem` depends on the value of `openTab`. When doing

```
const foo = bar === 42 ? [1,2] : 3
```

`foo` will be inferred as `number[] | 3`, it will not be adjusted when using the condition again.

But you can add the information yourself through type assertions:

```
@click="
  openTab === 1 ? getArticleList(rootItem as string) : getPriceClass(rootItem as string[])
"
```